# How to share an annotation across multiple elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this in my XSD (excerpt):

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:element name="int1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="baseStructMember">
          <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:byte" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:byte" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="step" type="xs:byte" use="optional">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                *** Description of the step goes here. ***
              </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="int2">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="baseStructMember">
          <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:short" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:short" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="step" type="xs:short" use="optional" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="int4">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="baseStructMember">
          <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="step" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:choice>
```

I want to add annotation to `step` attributes. As you see, I added it in `int1`. All `step` attributes (also in `int2`, `int4`...) are of different types, but have same meaning, so the annotation should be same.

Is there any way I could share one annotation across all `step` attributes?

Or define `step` externally, together with annotation and reuse it (like with `attributeGroup`), but allow for different attribute types?

Comment: See [Internal entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-internal-ent). You can declare it once and reuse in many places. There are also external entities, but they are considered a vulnerability.

Comment: After doing some reading I got this working. How about adding an answer so I would accept it?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, I'll happily upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by lexicore, this is possible with entities. This is a feature of any XML document, not only XSD.

Entities need to be defined in a DTD section. In my case the beginning of my XSD file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE xs:schema [
  <!ENTITY Doc-Step "*** Description of the step goes here. ***">
]>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...
```

From now on, `Doc-Step` can be used anywhere in the document as `&Doc-Step;`, and it will be replaced with proper string by XML parser:

```
<xs:attribute name="step" type="xs:byte" use="optional">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">&Doc-Step;</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

As the `@Doc-Step;` can be used in multiple places, this allows to reuse the documentation. Another nice feature is that it allows to gather all documentation strings  in one place - great for maintenance.